# Is it possible to have a generated column based on another table?

Tags: sql, database-design, count, subquery, sql-view

I was wonder if it was possible to create a generated column by using a group by query. For example, in the diagram below, is it possible to have the quantity of a equipment be generated based on the number of asset that matches it's foreign key?

[image]

Comment: Probably not (at least not in any database with which I'm familiar), but you can easily enough write a query to do this.

Comment: Not as a materialized column in a table. But you could create a view from a query that retrieves the tables column plus the computed column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with a computed column. If you wanted to store and maintain such information, you would need trigger code for every DML operation on table  `asset` , which makes things rather complex.

You can, on the other hand, create a view:

```
create view v_equipment
select e.*, 
    (select count(*) from asset a where a.equipment_id = e.equipment_id) as quantity
from equipment e
```

This gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your data. You can query the view directly instead of the table whenever you need the `quantity` information.